# not possible to set the "R home directory path" in Bluesky Statistics

Tags: r

I have problems in setting the "R home directory path" with the latest 64bit release of Bluesky Statistics (6.20.7235). After running the software for the first time, I received the following error:

> Error: Cannot Launch BlueSky Statistics! Please make sure:
>
> R_HOME configuration variable is pointing to the correct version of R.

Then, I set the "R home directory path" as follows, but I still got the above  error: **C:/Program Files/BlueSky Statistics/R-3.6.1**

I have the same problem when installing also the 32bit latest version, but not with the 64/32 bit stable release (6.10.7107). There are not other versions of R installed in my laptop.

Here are additional information of my laptop:
OS: Windows 8 64 bit;
CPU: Intel Celeron N2840 2.16 GHz;
RAM: 4 GB.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't paste links to images of your `code / error messages`. It would be much better to copy/paste your  `code / error messages` into your question. See my EDIT please.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue you can try following:
Find the following location:

C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\AppData\Roaming

In the above location you will see a folder named BlueSky. Delete this BlueSky folder to perform the manual cleanup. Launch BlueSky Statistics application and defaults will load automatically and also the BlueSky folder will be created.

Comment: This solution did not work to me, but the great BlueSky Statistics Support fixed the issue! The problem was a missing dll due to a failed installation of Microsoft .Net Framework. Thank you so much, you saved me!

Comment: We have added the netstandard ver 2.0 dll with our setup so no user should see this issue anymore.