# BlueSky Statistics: Error setting the “R_HOME directory path” preventing its start

Tags: r, rgui

I experienced the same problem as described in this post:
[not possible to set the "R home directory path" in Bluesky Statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58746971/not-possible-to-set-the-r-home-directory-path-in-bluesky-statistics)
But I was asked to open a new question for my case.

**The Problem:**

When I start the newly installed BlueSky Statistics program the following error message appears:

`Error: Cannot Launch BlueSky Statistics! Please make sure:
R_HOME configuration variable is pointing to the correct version of R.`

But setting the R_HOME path manually, (to the R Version that came with BlueSky Statistics) even in system variables does not make BlueSky Statistics work. (I took care that the path is set with correct "/" ).

**My Setup:**

- Windows 10 Pro
- 64bit

**What I have tried:**

- I tried all solutions in the mentioned post, but none of them worked.
- I deleted all other R versions and their remaining files from my hard disk and tried different versions of BlueSky Statistics.
- I always deleted the BlueSky folder in the Roaming folder in between every try.
- I installed the newest BlueSky-Statistics-Open-Source-x64-v**6.30.7341**.34565.exe
  and even the one reported in the other thread to be working anyways, version x64-v**6.10.7107**.24021, does not work for me either.

**Possible Solution:**
The other thread mentioned a missing dll file belonging to .net. 
If someone could post a link to this particualte version of the dll or the .net download, I would be happy to try if that works.

I highly appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing dll file is already in the newest BlueSky-Statistics-Open-Source-x64-v6.30.7341.34565.exe. Please try the following
Try this, please rename the "R-core" to say "R-core2" under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\
And now launch the BlueSky Statistics application.

If you still see the issue rename the other "R-core" as well, under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\

And now launch the BlueSky Statistics application.

Comment: Today, a Saturday, I finally wrote an E-mail to the BlueSky Statistics support, and got a lightning fast response from Aaron, helping me with the solution you can find above by the user named Val Athaide. I only needed to change the name of the "R-core" folder under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ and the BlueSky Statistics Software started!